# Material-UI Autocomplete disable options present in array

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use the `<Autocomplete />` Material-UI component as per their [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/).

Their example shows how to disable autocomplete by using the `getOptionDisabled` prop function as follows:

```
getOptionDisabled={option => option === timeSlots[0] || option === timeSlots[2]}
```

Let's say that I have an array that I am dynamically generating of timeSlots that I would like to disable,  `timeSlotsArr`, how could I use this prop to exclude all options that are present inside the `timeSlotsArr` array?

My current code, which is not working, looks like this:

```
<Autocomplete
  options={timeSlots}
  getOptionDisabled={option => option === timeSlotsArr.indexOf(option}
  style={{ width: 300 }}
  renderInput={params => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      label="Disabled options"
      variant="outlined"
      fullWidth
      inputProps={{
        ...params.inputProps,
        autoComplete: 'disabled', // disable autocomplete and autofill
      }}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: getOptionDisabled={option => timeSlotsArr.indexOf(option) !== -1}

Answer (score 9):

Wouldn't this be enough if you want to disable all the options in the dropdown?

```
getOptionDisabled={option => true}
```

As far as I understand you only pass a function that will return a boolean, so that would do it, right?

Also, your code is not working because it is comparing one of the options in the dropdown with what indexOf returns, which is -1 if it wasn't found, the index if it was. That is never going to be true. You could change it to:

```
getOptionDisabled={option => !!timeSlotsArr.find(option)}
```

If you use indexOf, the option would the index 0 would return false too, and you wouldn't want that.

Comment: how to disable the dropdown itself instead of disable all the options.

Comment: Not sure which version the above might be but now you can use `readOnly` prop from `AutoComplete`

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
getOptionDisabled={(option) => !!timeSlotsArr.find(element => element === option)}
```